# How to upload a JSON that includes an image file to a Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, rest, fetch-api

I am currently using the fetch API to post a JSON object to a REST API created with Spring Boot. I am using formData to read in the form data and store it in a JSON object:

```
 const data = new FormData(form);
 const formJson = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
 let responsePromise = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/student?id=" + studentId, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(formJson)
        });
```

The Spring Boot backend expects a JSON that corresponds to the Student entity class, which will eventually be stored in my database:

```
@PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Student> updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student, @RequestParam Long id) {
        Student currentDatabaseEntry = studentService.getStudent(id);
        currentDatabaseEntry.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());

        ...

        return new ResponseEntity<>(currentDatabaseEntry , HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }
```

This works fine.

Now, I have added a variable to the Student entity, which is of type `byte[]` and is suppossed to store an image of the student. So, I want to add an entry to my JSON object with key `image` and the value being a multipart file (the value of an input field of type "file").

From what I have read on the internet, it seems that whenever I want to upload a file, I should not upload a JSON, but instead the formData object. I fail to see how to handle this request on my backend though - doesn't Spring Boot expect the `@RequestBody` of the PUT request to be a JSON that resembles my Student entity?

Anyways, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I'd expect the image in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which would be a `String`. You just need to decode/encode it somewhere...

Comment: Sometimes putting everything into a single JSON is a bad idea. I don't really recall, but sending an image using a dedicated endpoint would be better from several perspectives (payload foot print, memory consumption, unnecessary Base64-encoding, etc). A more advanced (and more powerful) option would be implementing a single endpoint accepting multipart with both "data" JSON and "blobs" multiparts served in a single endpoint (if I'm not mistaken about the HTTP message payloads here), but this will probably have small (if any) compatibility with REST toolsets like OpenAPI.

Comment: As a side note, being RESTful, would probably be better to have `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/students/{studentId}` for your JSON payloads, and `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/students/{studentId}/pic` for your student image. This would also eliminate the need of encoding the profile picture in the JSON response, would allow cache the image response just by using a dedicated URL, would be natively supported, etc.

Comment: thx a lot for your comment, fluffy! I will probably go with two different endpoints then, one for the student information and one for the student image. That means I have to send to PUT requests though when updating both the image and the information. I figured it would be better to have just one request (performance-wise) but, I guess I am mistaken.

Comment: @Luk Usually, uploading profile image is mostly a rare operation, so I guess you'll need to `PUT` the profile info often, but `PUT` the profile image rarely. So, I'm almost sure you'll make it work by implementing two scenarios for both `PUT`s (usually like other WWW services do: uploading an image is usually a dedicated scenario). Also note, that having the endpoints split apart, you don't need to bake the image into huge JSON every time the client requests it. I bet you get the idea. Good luck!

Comment: allright, thx a lot! Just one last question: Does this mean I have to create an entity dedicated to my profile picture? I don't see how I could have this information in my student entity then. For example: When I send a GET request to my student-endpoint, it returns a student object, which I parse to a JSON. I could no longer do this if there is a BLOB variable in my student object. So I guess I need an extra entity just for my profile picture, am I right?

Comment: @Luk From the representation perspective, controllers, you'll deal with raw `InputStream`/`OutputStream` only (don't really remember how it's done in Spring MVC, but this is trivial). From the domain perspective, services, you'll (most likely) need a dedicated repository abstraction so that your blobs could be stored apart of the entities (so it could be an RDBMS, file system, blob storage, Amazon S3, whatever) -- of course with some logic behind.

Comment: @Luk From the data perspective, repository, I don't think you need an entity (I don't really know what you mean by this term, but I'm assuming you mean JPA/Hibernate, right?). Storing blobs even _may be a part of the database_, but I don't think you have to pay for performance like that and fuse "data" and "blobs" together. Having that said, in this case "entity" can be a simple byte stream identified by the ID that also identifies the student row in the database. Some prefer storing blobs right in the database, I wouldn't, but _you choose_.

Comment: @Luk And one more thing (as a side note, most likely unrelated to your _current_ project): being RESTful enough, depending on your blob repository implementation, you can even return a redirect to another service that only serves "static" content using HTTP 302 Found so that your service becomes somewhat more distributed and decentralized (looking more like a microservice, ha). In any case, as a general idea and a rule of thumb, data and blobs usually are processed apart, not together. Hope these comments shed some more light.

Comment: wow, thx a lot again! You are right, I am referring to JPA/Hibernate with "entity". I kind of use this term interchangeably with "database" - it is the Java representation of my database after all. If I understand you correctly - as data and blobs seem to be treated independently - it would be best to have a second database table explicitly for my profile picture, where entries can be identified by an ID that also idntifies the student row of my student database table. I will try that tmrw.